# Android sharing files between apps

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-settings

Hi I am trying to create an app that accepts files from other applications. I tried this tutorial, http://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/setup-sharing.html as well as this one, http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-sdk-receiving-data-from-the-send-intent--mobile-14878 and nothing seems to work.

here is my manifest,

```
...

<activity
            android:name="com.example.activities.mainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <data android:mimeType="application/*" />

            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
...
```

Yet still for some reason my application won't show up if I try to share files with it from dropbox or anything else. I've tried different mime types, using SEND instead of SEND_MULTIPLE, and starting a clean application project and nothing.
Thanks

EDIT:
Essentially what I want to do is have my app show up in the share menu for all other applications. I managed to get a complete action using... pop up, but this isn't what I'm looking for. Unfortunately all google searches result in the info above.

Comment: Have a look at the manifest for the email client in aosp: https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_email/blob/master/AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Thanks @ChrisStratton. I've tried to read through and add anything relevant from their manifest into mine (even tried every permission) and I still get nothing. Is there anything that needs to be performed at the application level?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that I have solved it. for mime type rather than having `"application/*"` all you need is `*/*`. For some reason, most files are opened as text/plain mime type including excel files. Odd.